# uploading csv to database fails on cells that are null

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Django 2.0

PostgreSQL 10

It is crucial that my app allows users to upload data in bulk, for which they can upload a csv file. However for any field that is non-string, if a cell on the csv file is Null then it returns the following error:

> ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD
>   format."]

This exception was copied in the case of a empty cell under the Date column, however it's the same for int and float.

The exception is straightforward. However according to the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer),

> the value None is written as the empty string

although this is stated under the *csv.writer* section and not under *csv.reader*.

I'm having a hard time understanding why the ORM is not converting empty strings to None or Null values that the database does understand, and as stated in my *models.py*, it accepts.

**models.py:**

```
class Control(models.Model):
    date  = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=True, blank=True)
    kilos = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
class ControlFileUpload(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'csv_upload.html')

    def post(self, request):
        file = request.FILES['csv_file']
        _control_bulk_data_upload(file) #imported from utils.py
        return render(request, 'csv_upload_success.html')
```

**utils._control_bulk_data_upload:**

```
import csv, datetime
from app.models import Control

def _control_bulk_data_upload(csv_file):
    path = default_storage.save("{}_{}".format(datetime.utcnow(), csv_file.name), ContentFile(csv_file.read()))
    with open(path) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(reader) #skip headers
        for row in reader:
            Control.objects.create(
                date      = row[0],
                kilos     = row[1],
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the value is None before writing to database.

```
date = row[0] if row[0] else datetime.datetime.today()
```

And use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to insert data with one query instead of having query in a loop. It's much more efficient this way.

```
temp_data = []
with open(path) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader) #skip headers
    for row in reader:
        csv_data = Control()
        csv_data.date = row[0] if row[0] else datetime.datetime.today()
        csv_data.kilos = row[1] if row[1] else 0
        temp_data.append(csv_data)

if len(temp_data) > 0:
    bulk_create = Control.objects.bulk_create(temp_data)
```

Comment: but I don't want to assign _datetime.today()_ or _0_'s, I want the fields to be stored as NULL

Comment: Then change else to None.

Comment: Just want to add additional clarification since I struggled a lot with this. My data was coming from a dataframe that had "None" in the fields which were supposed to be null. However, Django expect you to pass in None as the python value for Null, not the string. Hope this helps ..